# What could be the base source of sustenance in the underworld?

Tags: food, underground

On the surface of the world the sun is the source of energy for plants and the foo chain goes up from that. How could a similar base for a food chain be established in the large world below?

I am looking first for "realistic" options, so anything like methane eating bacteria would work. I am also open to magical options, like luminescent crystals of which mosses/lichens feed.

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding Per the Help Center. This is not the right forum for brainstorming quesitons. You need to ask questions with the expectation of selcting a best answer based on objective criteria, even if you never do. Please see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask] for more information. This Q is especially problematic because you're open to realistic and magical anwers, making the Q open-ended, which is specifically prohibited.

Comment: This question is definitely about building a fictional world, but open ended brainstorming questions like this are not permitted on this site.

Comment: Is there a way for me to reword the question to be in line with the requirements? Does "What is the base source of food in underworld setting?" work?

Comment: Right now I see "What does the Minotaur eat?" as a question with 53 upvotes. I don't know how is that different. I can reword to "What do denizens of the underworld eat?"

Comment: Asking what would x creature eat is very different than asking what does every creature in an environment eat. We have a requirement that questions not be overly broad and as written this question has the potential for far too many valid answers. This is before you account for any answer that brainstorm a magical solution for you out of whole cloth.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... What about **a thermal mushroom**?

I don’t mean an mushroom that makes heat, I mean one that *eats heat*. Perhaps it is a super-basic but large organism that manufactures the compounds of life by reaching its roots deep into the ground and using the difference in temperature between the dark caverns where it is found and the deeper crust/upper mantle to extract energy from the heat of the planet’s core. This way, it can apply that energy to turn basic chemicals, like carbon dioxide or limestone or what have ye, into the stuff it needs to grow. Then, when it has excess, it grows mushrooms that are edible to some species of subterranean creature, and the food chain starts there.

Seems plausible enough, if that’s what you’re going for.

Comment: Thanks! I like this - they can consume the heat from the hell below.

Answer (score 0):

In real world subterranean ecosystems most of the ecology is based on nutrients from the surface transported into the system either by water or by animals that shelter in the caves but feed outside e.g bats (in the form of their bodies and waste products).

So you I suppose posit two 'parallel' ecosystems existing side by side in your subterranean world. The first is reliant on surface nutrients for survival which are transferred to the cavern from the surface via the two mechanisms described above. The second source as you hinted are methagenic microorgansims.

Combined the two sources of nutrients are sufficient to support a diverse network of fungi and animals filling niches equivalent to their surface dwelling counterparts. Only in this case none of the animals have eyes and instead use heat, sound/sonar sonar and smell/taste to navigate their world.